# What is the best way to store constant field in microservice architecture?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

Many servers use the same constants, it is necessary to organize a centralized changing them. What is the best way to store constant parameters in microservice architecture.

For example, we store static final int MAX_PEOPLE_COUNT = 100; This field use different microservices. If we change this value, all microservices should see it.

It would be great to have also the versioning of the parameter values.

Comment: What type of parameters are you talking about? Database servers? General environment variables..?

Comment: If they are constant there is no need to store them anywhere in particular, *if* you want to change them and the application should react then it gets interesting. What parameters specifically are you talking about?

Comment: hmm maybe a shared based utility service that stores all the parameters then each microservice can periodically read them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you are in the Spring ecosystem, the best way would be to use the **Spring Cloud Config Server**. You can readily and easily get the steps to setup a config server in the [Spring Cloud Config Server guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) and [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html) too. The documentation is pretty much straightforward.

You can even use **Zookeeper** as a centralized config service with Spring Cloud. More details on that in this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cloud-config-part-3-zookeeper-backend).

Comment: In case of use Spring Cloud Config i don't like syntax @Value("${MAX_PEOPLE_COUNT}"). 
Maybe there is another syntax  in Spring Cloud?

Comment: @FranzF According to the documentation, you can access the config `The client may access any value in the Config Server using the traditional mechanisms (e.g.  @ConfigurationProperties, @Value("${…​}") or through the Environment abstraction)`

Comment: @FranzF could you please elaborate about not liking the `@Value` syntax?

Comment: @ Madhu Bhat Because we have legacy project and the number of constants is more than 200. A suitable way would be to use the key/value store like map.

Comment: @FranzF even if you have more than 200 configs, using it wouldn't be an issue with `@Value`. You can have the key in `@Value("${…​}")` and the value of the same would be assigned to the field in the java class. And having specifically a map like store wouldn't be possible with spring cloud

Comment: Found the answer in the book Newman Sam. Building Microservices. There are two option: 1)  Static data as code in each microservice 2)  Push static data into a service of its own right. But Newman Sam write : "I’d try to push for keeping this data in configuration files or directly in code, as it is the simple option for most case"

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to store cross-micro-service configuration. Starting with all commons database. We specifically using [consul by HashiCorp](https://www.consul.io/) in order to store our cross-micro-service configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the Argument by @Madhu Bhat, in my opinion also the best way is to use Spring Cloud Config Server [(getting started)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)

Now specific to your use-case that couple of microservices share some common *configurable value* (I have intentionally changed the word from CONSTANT to CONFIGURABLE, as by definition constant is not something that is supposed to be changed), *best practice* to use configuration files in spring is as follows:

Suppose you have 3 microservices in your eco-system (hypothetical scenario)

- billing-service
- cart-service
- product-service

As a best practice, you should maintain configuration file at various levels -

- **microservice + environment specific** config file e.g. *billing-dev.properties or billing-test.properties*
  This property file would contain properties that are specific to a particular environment for a particular service. Billing service might have certain properties that are different for your *dev* environment and different for a *test* environment. You can have as many properties/configuration files as your environments.
- **Microservice level** – properties common for all the environments for particular microservices e.g. *billing.properties*
- **application.properties** – this property file contains those properties that are common for all the microservices or multiple microservices (*your use-case*) e.g. billing and product service both need some configurable property.

**Property/configuration resolution:**

From microservice prospective (say billing service), any property would be first searched in the first-mentioned property file (billing-test.properties or billing-dev.properties) according to what environment you have specified on the service startup by configuration by property [(see here in detail)](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_environment_repository)

```
spring.profiles.active
```

If the desired property is not found in environment specific property then fallback configuration file to be searched would be second-mentioned file generic service configuration file for all environments (*billing.properties*).

If property is not found in above mentioned two files that it would be resolved by *application.yml* file